# How do I json_encode without those quotes for the coordinates in leaflet geojson polygon?

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson, php

I have a field name:  'coordinates'
I have the coordinates stored in there:  like this:
[[ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]]

when I json_encode($geojson);

I get this output:

```
"coordinates": "[[ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] "
```

notice the double quotes

it needs to be:

```
"coordinates": [[ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
```

How do I json_encode without those quotes for the coordinates?

Here is my full code.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $properties = $row;
    $geometry = $row;
    # Remove fields
    unset($properties['coordinates']);
    unset($properties['type']);
    unset($geometry['unitID']);
    unset($geometry['milesSq']);
    unset($geometry['acres']);
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'properties' => $properties,
        'geometry' => array($geometry)        
    );
    # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}

echo json_encode($geojson);
```

results:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"unitID":"001","milesSq":"111.000000","acres":"222.000000"},"geometry":[{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":"[[[-109.048595341028587, 40.834756771179649], [-108.966734749488324, 40.562222787215255],  [-109.048595341028587, 40.834756771179649]]]"}]}]}
```

ON JS:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post", 
            url: "<?php echo $this->app_lib->FOLDER['admin'].$this->router->class ?>/buscador", 
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {clat:center.lat, clng:center.lng, zoom:zoo, minlat:min.lat, minlng:min.lng, maxlat:max.lat, maxlng:max.lng, layers:<?php echo json_encode($layers); ?>}, 
            success: function(result){
              //if (data.error) {
                //map.removeLayer(data.points); 
                $("#loader").hide()
                $.each(result, function(index, layer) {
                    if(layer.data.layer == 3){
                            $.each(layer.data.features, function(index, polygons) {
                                console.log(polygons.geometry.coordinates);
                                var poly = L.geoJson(campus, {
                                style: function (feature) {
                                    return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                                },
                                onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
                            });
                            map.addLayer(poly); 
});
```

Comment: What is the data type of the coordinates column? It looks like text in your question. As far as I know there is no array data type in MySQL

Comment: you're storing the coordinate data as a text field in the database?

Comment: Yes.. I have a longtext field and placing the polygon in this following format [[-3.96881103515625, 40.56510079313928],[-4.0045166015625, 40.49829983826093],[-3.856201171875, 40.49934411527887]]

Answer (score 3):

In the javascript code the array is treated as a string so  try to parse this sting as json before using , then assign the result to ***coordinates*** . So if your result in success function is ***result*** , parse its coordinates attribute before using it this is example how to do so :

```
      result = {
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "unitID": "001",
            "milesSq": "111.000000", "acres": "222.000000"
        },
        "geometry": [
            {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": "[[[-109.048595341028587, 40.834756771179649], [-108.966734749488324, 40.562222787215255],  [-109.048595341028587, 40.834756771179649]]]"
            }
          ]
        }
       ]
     }


$.each(result.features, function (index, polygons) {
    $.each(polygons.geometry, function (index, geo) {
    console.log(geo.coordinates);
    var coordinates = JSON.parse(geo.coordinates);
    geo.coordinates = coordinates;


})
})


console.log(result)

  ///////  here u can start using the result object
  ///////   the leaflet code goes here
```

**OR** in the php code you can  decode the stringified array before passing  it  like this :

```
 $geometry['coordinates']=json_decode($geometry['coordinates']);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I am passing directly to the JSON Objects into L.geoJson function.                                                  var poly = L.geoJson(campus, {style: function (feature) {  return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
},onEachFeature: onEachFeature,});map.addLayer(poly);

Comment: First thing you should do  in the success function is to iterate on the result object returned by php and parse the coordinates . I will edit answer to give example

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the second approach - decoding the coordinates in PHP using the extra single line. The result has the benefit of being a valid GeoJSON, no client-side hacks in JS required.

Comment: I prefer that too ;), we should try to keep the client side clean and let the server handle the data processing.

Answer (score 0):

It works but abit tricky way...

$.each(layer.data.features, function(index, polygons) {
                                var coordinates = JSON.parse(polygons.geometry.coordinates);
                                var values = [];
                                var coord = [];
                                for(var i = 0, l = coordinates.length; i < l; i++) {
                                    values.push(coordinates[i]);
                                }
                                coord.push(values);
                                var campus = {
                                        'type': 'Feature',
                                        'properties': {
                                                'name': polygons.properties.name, 
                                                'category': polygons.properties.category,
                                                'description': polygons.properties.description,
                                                'style': {
                                                    weight: 2,
                                                    color: polygons.properties.style.color,
                                                    opacity: 1,
                                                    fillColor: polygons.properties.style.color,
                                                    fillOpacity: 0.4
                                                }},
                                        'geometry': {
                                                'type': 'Polygon', 
                                                'coordinates': coord
                                            }
                                };

```
                            var poly  = L.geoJson(campus,  {
                                                        style: function (feature) {
                                                            return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                                                        },
                                                        onEachFeature: onEachPolygonFeature,

                            });
                            map.addLayer(poly); 

                        });
```